# How do I select all data.table columns that are in a second data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have several data.tables that have the same columns, and one that has some extra columns. I want to rbind them all but only on the common columns

with data.frames I could simply do

```
 rbind(df1[,names(df2)],df2,df3,...)
```

I can of course write all the column names in the form

```
  list(col1,col2,col3,col4)
```

but this is not elegant, nor feasible if one has `1,000` variables

I am sure there is a way and I am not getting there - any help would be appreciated

Comment: Did you try `rbind(df1[, names(df2), with = FALSE],df2,df3,...)`?

Comment: Yes that works, thanks - I am not sure exactly why but I will look into that

Comment: do you have `NA`'s in any one of the `data.table`'s?

Answer (score 3):

May be you can try:

```
DT1 <- data.table(Col1=1:5, Col2=6:10, Col3=2:6)
DT2 <- data.table(Col1=1:4, Col3=2:5)
DT3 <- data.table(Col1=1:7, Col3=1:7)
lst1 <- mget(ls(pattern="DT\\d+"))

ColstoRbind <- Reduce(`intersect`,lapply(lst1, colnames))
# .. "looks up one level"
res <- rbindlist(lapply(lst1, function(x) x[, ..ColstoRbind]))
res
#    Col1 Col3
# 1:    1    2
# 2:    2    3
# 3:    3    4
# 4:    4    5
# 5:    5    6
# 6:    1    2
# 7:    2    3
# 8:    3    4
# 9:    4    5
#10:    1    1
#11:    2    2
#12:    3    3
#13:    4    4
#14:    5    5
#15:    6    6
#16:    7    7
```

#### Update

As @Arun suggested in the comments, this might be better

```
rbindlist(lapply(lst1, function(x) {
          if(length(setdiff(colnames(x), ColstoRbind))>0) {  
               x[, ..ColstoRbind]
               }
              else x}))
```

Comment: I want to add a comment. I am sure the solution works, but it failed with the amount of data I had (why use data.table after all unless I have a lot of data) - my system,crashed many times even after I kept only the minimum data needed on the workspace. In the end I used rbind.fill even though I was ensuring only teh same columns were in, but since it converted it to a data.frame that seem to solve the crashes. I am sharing this in the spirit of helping others - I have 12 GB of RAM and I am using a server version

Comment: @user1617979, The above solution is inefficient because column subsets makes *deep* copies in data.table, and this is making copies even when not necessary - i.e., when the columns are already as you required. Question: What's your R and data.table version?

Comment: @Arun Glad that you responded.  I was trying one of the data.frame solutions which I doubted that it will be inefficient.

Comment: @Arun I updated with your suggestion.  Perhaps, it is in the right direction?

Comment: Great! You might need to use `1.9.3` version to make use of  `use.names=TRUE` argument to bind by names. `rbindlist` doesn't match names by default.

Comment: I was using data.table 1.9.2,. is is possible that since it failed with the 2 data.table solutions with the data I had and it did not fail with rbind.fill (from plyr) that there may be a bug in data.table? (which well could have been fixed in 1.9.3) - I aknowledge that the reason I was using DT was because dplyr/plyr were not working well. The tables I was trying to rbind had 18 columns - one had 3.8 million rows but I only wanted about 1 million (I did not mention I had a row filter as that was always working and it was unnecessary IMHO) - Thanks for the help, I learned a lot

Comment: np, it's a very old answer but we're making a push to highlight with=F is often not needed in case new learners happen upon old answers